# PEP-8: module at top of file

Tags: python, pep8

Desiring to improve my Python style, I ran a PEP-8 style checker on one of my script and it complained about something I don't know how to fix.  The prologue of the script is something like:

```
#! /bin/env python3

import sys
import os

exe_name = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))
bin_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
inst_dir = os.path.dirname(bin_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, inst_dir+'/path/to/packages')

import mypackage.mymodule
```

and the style checker complain on the `import mymodule` line, stating that it should be a top of file.  But I obviously can't move it before setting the path where it will be found.  Is there a good way to achieve this (mandating an environment variable or a shell wrapper are not what I find better than my current code) while respecting PEP-8 recommendations at the same time?

Comment: PEP-8 recommendations are just that: recommendations. I'd just tell the linter to ignore that one line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that's was my first inclination (rules are either simple and exceptions are needed, or complex and not followed as nobody remember them) but I wondered if there was a common idiom that I was unaware of.

Comment: Nah, this looks like a good exception.

Comment: Just append the line with `# noqa`, so that lint would ignore it, like so `import mypackage.mymodule # noqa`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid path manipulation, you may be able to do so by using the under-known `.pth` feature.

`sys.path` should begin with the directory containing the main program either by name or by reference as ''.  I assume that the file importing `mymodule` is not part of `mypackage`, so that the '' entry is not useful for importing `mymodule`.

`sys.path` should end with the `site-packages` directory for the executing binary.  That is the normal place for added packages.  If you do not want to move `mypackage` into `site-packages`, you can extend the latter 'vitually' by putting a `mystuff.pth` file in it.  It should contain one line: the path to the directory *containing* `mypackage`.  Call it `myprojects`. Then `mypackage` and any other package in `myprojects` can be imported as if they were in `site-packages`.

One advantage of .pth files is that you can put identical copies in multiple site-packages directories.  For instance, I have multiple projects in `F:/python`.  I have multiple versions of Python installed.  So I have put `python.pth` containing that one line in the site-packages for each.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy would be to put the `sys.path` related code in separate file and import it in working code file.

So, I will split above code in two files. One named `my_module.py` and other named `working_module.py`

Now `my_module` will contain below lines

```
import sys
import os

exe_name = os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))
bin_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
inst_dir = os.path.dirname(bin_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, inst_dir+'/path/to/packages')
```

and `working_module` will contain

```
import my_module
import mypackage.mymodule
```

because we are importing `my_module` before `mypackage`, it will execute the path related code before and your package will be available in path.

Comment: Imports shouldn't alter functionality like that. It's super-duper bad form, and it doesn't make it clear *why* your code is failing when you take out the seemingly unneeded import.

Comment: @aryamccarthy it is not changing/altering any functionality. You can write imports in another file if it too long.

Comment: Adding another file just to respect a style guidance does not seem such a good idea to me.

Comment: @AProgrammer it doesn't seems right then it would be better to ask Pep8 to silent/ignore these lines.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `importlib` module (python 3.5) or `imp` for python 2.7 to load `mypackage.mymodule` programatically. Both have the same purpose:

> mechanisms used to implement the import statement

This question might help you more:
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#examples

https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

Comment: To what end? Only to not have an import statement after the `sys.path` manipulation? Just mark the line as ignored, never write more complicated code just to satisfy a style-guide recommendation.